# Knex : update a slice of randomly selected records

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, knex.js

I have a table that stores gifts :

```
export interface Gift {
  id: number
  type : string
  claim_status: string
  user_id?: number
}
```

When a user claims one or multiple gifts, i want to select randomly some gifts and update them with the user_id. I tried using the knex `limit`function but it doesn't work for updating.

```
export const claimGifts = async (
  user : User,
  numberToClaim: number,
  trx: Knex.Transaction
) => {
  const gifts = await db<Gift>('gift')
    .where({claim_status : 'available'})
//   limit the amount of updated to numberToClaim be slicing randomly
    .update({user_id : user.id, claim_status : 'claimed'}, '*')
    .transacting(trx)
  return gifts
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: How would you do it in plain SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first construct a SQL query, and then convert it to Knex usage.

I would use nested query for selecting random entries, something like:

```sql
Update gift set user_id = 'MY_USER_ID' Where id IN (Select inner_g.id from gifts as inner_g where claim_status='available' Order by RAND() Limit 3)
```

When it converted to Knex, it looks like:

```js
 const gifts = await db<Gift>('gift')
    .update({
      user_id: user.id,
      claim_status: 'claimed',
    })
    .whereIn(
      'id',
      db('gift as inner_g')
        .columns('inner_g.id')
        .where({ claim_status: 'available' })
        .orderBy(db.raw('RAND()') as any)
        .limit(3)
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, that works well. 
I wanted to add that creating the SQL query first to come up with the knex code is really the best advice you could have gived.
Also, I am using PostGresSQL and therefore, the RAND function is actually ```random()```.